# Is it possible for workers to consume based on topic?

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp, node-amqplib

I understand that you can send messages directly to a queue using `channel.sendToQueue`, and this creates a tasks-and-workers situation, where only one consumer will handle each task.

I also understand that you can use `channel.publish` with a topic-based exchange, and messages will be routed to queues based on the routing key. To my understanding, though, this will always broadcast to all subscribers on any matching queues.

I would essentially like to use the topic-based exchange, but only have one consumer handle each task. I've been through the documentation, and I don't see a way to do this.

My use-case:

I have instances of a microservice set up in multiple locations. There might be two in California, three in London, one in Singapore, etc. When a task is created, the only thing that matters is that it's handled by one of the instances in a given location.

Of course, I can create hundreds of queues named "usa-90210", "uk-ec1a", etc. It just seems like using topics would be much cleaner. It would also be more flexible, given the ability to use wildcards.

If this isn't a feature of RabbitMQ, I'm open to other thoughts or ideas as well.

***UPDATE***

As per istepaniuk's suggestion, I've tried creating two workers, each binding their own queue to the exchange:

```
const connectionA = await amqplib.connect('amqp://guest:guest@127.0.0.1:5672');
const channelA = await connectionA.createChannel();
channelA.assertExchange('test_exchange', 'topic', { durable: false });
await channelA.assertQueue('test_queue_a', { exclusive: true });
channelA.bindQueue('test_queue_a', 'test_exchange', 'usa.*');
await channelA.consume('test_queue_a', () => { console.log('worker a'); }, { noAck: true });

const connectionB = await amqplib.connect('amqp://guest:guest@127.0.0.1:5672');
const channelB = await connectionB.createChannel();
channelB.assertExchange('test_exchange', 'topic', { durable: false });
await channelB.assertQueue('test_queue_b', { exclusive: true });
channelB.bindQueue('test_queue_b', 'test_exchange', 'usa.*');
await channelB.consume('test_queue_b', () => { console.log('worker b'); }, { noAck: true });

const pubConnection = await amqplib.connect('amqp://guest:guest@127.0.0.1:5672');
const pubChannel = await pubConnection.createChannel();
pubChannel.assertExchange('test_exchange', 'topic', { durable: false });
pubChannel.publish('test_exchange', 'usa.90210', Buffer.from(''));
```

Unfortunately, both consumers are still receiving the message.

```
worker a
worker b
```

Answer (score 1):

**Yes.**

> I would essentially like to use the topic-based exchange, but only have one consumer handle each task. I've been through the documentation, and I don't see a way to do this.

Use a topic exchange and have your consumers declare and bind their own queues. What you describe is a very common scenario. It is outlined in the [tutorial 5, "Topics"](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-five-javascript.html).

Additionally, you can have multiple consumers share a queue (just don't declare it `exclusive`). This is described in [tutorial 2, "Workers"](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-javascript.html).

The multiple instances of consumers can declare the same queue and bindings, the operation is idempotent. Using `durable` queues (as opposed to `exclusive`) also means that the messages will queue up if all your consumers disappear or the network fails.

Comment: Thanks istepaniuk. I went over the topics page again, but I don't see any single consumer examples. I tried binding a separate queue to each consumer, but both consumers are still being triggered. Please check my code above.

Comment: @DaiBu Why wouldn't the two consumers receive that message? Both bind on `usa.*`, so both match on your test message `usa.90210`

Comment: Right. I think there was miscommunication. To be clear, I have tasks which need to be handled by the next available worker (out of a pool) at a given location. I basically want to say, "The next consumer that is free in Beverly Hills, USA, please handle this task." A topics exchange would need to single out the specific worker using a unique topic, correct? I need to be able to publish to a pool of workers and have only one pick up the task. Does this still fit in with your suggestion?

Comment: @DaiBu Ok, and you are on the right path anyway. If you don't declare the queue "exclusive" and start many consumers (sharing that same queue), the messages will be distributed among them, sharing load.

Just removing 'exclusive' and starting many "worker A" consumers will create such "A" pool that you want. Declaring (not asserting!) the exchange, queue and binding each time is fine, it's an idempotent operation.

Comment: Nevermind asserting vs. declaring, that seems to be something that changes between APIs but it's the same.